# Permission denied (even as root) on a mounted ISO image with Furius ISO Mount

Tags: filesystems, permissions, mount, cp, iso

I mounted a ISO image with [Furius ISO Mount](https://launchpad.net/furiusisomount). I cd to the mounted directory and tried to copy a file with

`sudo cp file /dir`

but cp writes error message

> cp: cannot stat `file': Permission denied

The permissions of `file` are `-r--r--r--`

`sudo chmod 777 file` writes

> chmod: cannot access `file': Permission denied

Do you know where the problem could be?

Comment: What are the permissions of 'file'?

Comment: see question edit

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17402/why-does-root-get-permission-denied-when-accessing-fuse-directory).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds to me like furiousisomount could be repsonsible for this issue. I know similar issues with broken file system modules and similar.

I usually mount ISOs via the loop device of the kernel. You can use it this way:

mount some.iso /mnt -o loop=/dev/loop0

Answer (score 3):

Furius ISO Mount relies on [FuseIso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FuseIso), which is a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem. FUSE allows users to provide their own filesystem drivers without using specific code in the kernel. FUSE filesystems are restricted to the user who runs the driver process by default. You need to pass the option `-o allow_root` or `allow_other` to the `fusermount` or `fuseiso` mounting command. This doesn't seem to be supported by Furius ISO Mount.