# What Does :/// Mean?

Tags: linux, path, url

The trash in Linux is shown under the path of trash:/// What does :/// mean?

I don't seem to be able to find the explanation of three slashes "///" anywhere online.

Comment: Possibly related: [Nautilus special URIs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/nautilus-special-uris)

Comment: That's actually nothing to do with Linux.  The operating system kernel does not know about this GVFS stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI), just as `https://stackexchange.com` is. A URI begins with the the scheme followed by `://` literally and the authority. Since `trash` is the scheme of a virtual directory tree, its authority has a root directory called `/`. Here you are, the syntax is: `scheme://authority`, so it is `trash:///`.

For more information about URIs, see [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

Comment: The `//` is part of the authority, not part of the separation between the scheme and the authority. Many file-like URLs, though, allow a "null" authority to represent the local host. Theoretically, one could write `trash://localhost/...` to differentiate between a file in the local trash can and a file in the trashcan of some other machine, or possibly even  `trash://bob@/...` to represent some other user's trash can. Most likely, though, whichever window manager is processing the `trash` URLs is making up its own semantics without regard to how URIs are defined in general.

Comment: See, for example, the [description of the `file` scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).