# Unlock LUKS partition using keyfile without root access?

Tags: non-root-user, luks, udisks

Is there any way to unlock LUKS partition using keyfile while not having root priviliges? (using sudo is not an option)

I know that *udisksctl* can open LUKS partition, however it can do it only with a passphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. And even solutions that apparently do it without root privileges, actually do have root privileges. This is just a basic requirement for mounting or accessing raw disk data. If you could do those without root priveleges, you could read files you have no permission to read (by reading and searching the raw data), and if you could mount you could mess up the VFS filesystem tree, possibly in creative ways that let you obtain permissions you're not supposed to have.

What you could do, if you already had read permission to the raw encrypted data, is implement everything needed to access it and extract files from it in software that runs without root permissions. So basically you'd treating a LUKS encrypted image file as you would a GPG-encrypted tar. If this is what you wanted, and for some reason absolutely had no root or sudo available, you'd usually use the tar in the first place since that's what already exists as a read-to-use solution.

To provide a more practical approach to your problem: keyfiles are passphrases and passphrases are keyfiles, really. Apart from some minor details (e.g. how it treats newlines), LUKS does not really make a distinction here. Keyfile just means it reads the passphrase from a file.

So you could just use keyfiles that are printable ASCII and don't have newlines in them.

That is, if *udisksctl* really doesn't support keyfiles. Kind of hard to understand why.

Comment: sorry, but this limitation applies to physical drive partitions, right? With an encrypted file container (owned by me) it seems I can open it without root, and just need root for the initial setup (with cryptmount utility). Or is there any magic hidden I overlooked? Thank you!

Comment: @Ilja ... "just need root for the initial setup" is opposite of "without root access". Regardless of container or partition, you need root access (or a helper program with root access, which is the same thing wrapped in a different package) or you can't setup dmcrypt, nor mount. Doing it all w/o root access would mean re-implementing the entire functionality in userspace, which is possible, but... why? Just use root! That's what it's there for!

Comment: and if by initial setup you meant luksFormat, no, you need root to open and mount it, if it seems that you can do without, there's certainly a helper involved somewhere that has root

Comment: thank you for your reply! And sorry my comment was quite off-topic in the context of the OP. My use-case is to mount a remote file (in an sshfs-directory) - and sshfs won't let me do any root actions inside of it. And also the cryptmount-utility (it's distinct from luks/cryptsetup) fail - apparently because - as you wrote - it uses root under the hood. After a lot of trying/reading I understand much more of the problem, but still don't see why it conceptually can't work, and can't formulate a good question either. That's why I abused this topic - sorry ;)

Comment: @Ilja "and sshfs won't let me do any root actions inside of it" doesn't make much sense to me, but it's true that fuse based filesystem-in-userspace often have odd behavior as they sometimes implement only a subset of functionality compared to a real filesystem. in particular you need random I/O on top of files, no idea if sshfs has issue with that - it's possible

Comment: the author of https://ruderich.org/simon/notes/encrypted-remote-backups#issues explains it as: "If you’re starting sshfs as non-root user then running cryptsetup will fail as FUSE prevents root from entering the mounted file system (this is designed to prevent attacks which confuse or hang root processes).". Your argument about device files is convincing, but that my usecase doesnt work still seems artificial/not-intrinsic. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @Ilja interesting, I didn't know about this at all https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17402/30851